# How to determine current status of web video (playing | stopped)

Tags: javascript, vb.net, flash, video

How can I determine when a user starts or stops playing a video on a web page?  For instance, the video on this page:

http://www.novamov.com/video/exm71hcwt1aly

I need to be able to determine this from a separate .NET application running on the client.

Comment: Well, this should have been your first question.  It could have saved you a lot of time if it's not possible.  I don't know of anyway.  Maybe there's an expert in JavaScript that could help you with this, but you're going to have to tag it as such if they are going to see your question.

Comment: ok, but i think that when i playing the video the flash process is runing too , so maybe i can read the status from the process by memory adress, but if i can do it with javascript it Better